# Cannot set property 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' of undefined

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I am trying to create api docs.But when I try to check working it is giving `Could not render n, see the console.` And on console it is giving `Cannot set property 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' of undefined`.
My code in Testing controller is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @SWG\Get(
     *   path="/api/testing/{mytest}",
     *   summary="Get Testing",
     *   operationId="testing",
     *   @SWG\Response(response=200, description="successful operation"),
     *   @SWG\Response(response=406, description="not acceptable"),
     *   @SWG\Response(response=500, description="internal server error"),
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="mytest",
     *          in="path",
     *          required=true,
     *          type="string"
     *      ),
     * )
     *
     */
    public function index(Request $request){
        echo $request->mytest;
    }
}
```

Route is

```
Route::get('/testing/{mytest}','TestingController@index');
```

It would be a great help for me if I could fix it. Thank you.

Comment: use laravel version of https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

Comment: I have used same versions. Still it is giving the error

Comment: I think this is an error in javascript, can you provide the error image?